# How to return to the position I clicked just now in HTML5 and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a list of articles in page of *A*. When I click on each link of the article in *A*, I will redirected to page *B* to be shown the article content.

If I click the "return" button，I will return to page *A*.

How can page *A* remember which article link was clicked most recently, and scroll to that link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where defining an event handler function (callback) the first parameter of that function is the event object.

The event object contains such information as the type of event, the exact HTML element that triggered the event, the exact position within the page.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
```

The above is available in the jQuery eventObject.

The "normal" JavaScript eventObject may have differently named properties referring to the position information. They may even be differently named across browsers.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    console.log(e.layerX, e.layerY);
};
```